# Formula for rotating vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

Let $u = (u_1, u_2)$ and $x=(x,y)$ a rotation of u by an angle θ. Then $\left\lVert u \right\rVert = \left\lVert x \right\rVert$

We know:
$$cosθ = {{u \cdot x}\over \left\lVert u \right\rVert \cdot \left\lVert x \right\rVert} = {{u \cdot x}\over \left\lVert u \right\rVert \cdot \left\lVert u \right\rVert} =  {{u \cdot x}\over \left\lVert u \right\rVert^2} =  {{u \cdot x} \over u \cdot u} \Leftrightarrow (u \cdot u)  cosθ = u \cdot x \tag 1 $$

Expanding $(1)$:
$$(u_1^2 +u_2^2)cosθ = u_1x +u_2y \tag 2 $$

We also know:
$$\left\lVert u \right\rVert = \left\lVert x \right\rVert \Leftrightarrow \sqrt{u_1^2 +u_2^2} = \sqrt{x^2 +y^2} \Rightarrow u_1^2 +u_2^2 = x^2 +y^2 \tag 3$$

For any set of $(u_1,u_2, θ)$ we now have a system of two equations and two unknowns. We should get two vectors that form an angle $θ$ with $u$ out of that.

But I was trying to combine these two formulas ($(2)$ and $(3)$) into a single generic one and I failed. Is it possible to do that?

Or could we solve $(1)$ for $x$ some way to get a vector equation for the rotation? $(x,y) = x_{something}\ cosθ \ (u_1, u_2) $ would be nice.

I know there is a formula for vector rotations using matrix transformations but I would like to know if it is possible to do the same thing with the aforementioned equations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $u_1,$ $u_2,$ and $\theta$ are given.
First solve for $y$ in Equation $(2)$:
$$ y = \frac1{u_2}(u_1^2 +u_2^2)\cos\theta - \frac{u_1}{u_2}x. \tag4$$

Now let $h = \frac1{u_2}(u_1^2 +u_2^2)\cos\theta$
and let $m = \frac{u_1}{u_2}.$
Note that for any given value of $u_1,$ $u_2,$ and $\theta,$
we can treat $h$ and $m$ as constants.
Likewise we can set $r = \sqrt{u_1^2 + u_2^2}$ and treat $r$ as a constant.
You don't really need to define these extra symbols, but they are a reminder of some important quantities that do not depend on $x$ or $y,$ and they let you write the equations a little quicker and therefore manipulate them a little easier.

Now we can write Equation $(4)$ as
$$ y = h - mx \tag5$$
and Equation $(3)$ as
$$ x^2 + y^2 = r^2 . \tag6$$

Use Equation $(5)$ to substitute for $y$ in Equation $(6)$:
$$ x^2 + (h - mx)^2 = r^2. $$

Expand $(h - mx)^2$ and collect the terms in $x^2$ and $x$; also make a single constant term:
$$ (m^2 + 1)x^2 - 2hmx + (h^2 - r^2) = 0. $$

This is a quadratic equation, $ax^2 + b + c=0$ with $a=m^2+1,$
$b = -2hm,$ and $c = h^2 - r^2.$ Solving it,
\begin{align}
x &= \frac{2hm \pm \sqrt{4h^2m^2 - 4(m^2 + 1)(h^2 - r^2)}}{2(m^2 + 1)}\\
 &= \frac{2hm \pm \sqrt{4h^2m^2 - 4(h^2m^2 + h^2 - (m^2+1)r^2)}}{2(m^2 + 1)}\\
 &= \frac{hm \pm \sqrt{(m^2+1)r^2 - h^2}}{m^2 + 1}.
\end{align}

Now let's put back the original symbols, but carefully:
\begin{align}
h^2 &= \frac1{u_2^2}(u_1^2 +u_2^2)^2\cos^2\theta = \frac{r^4}{u_2^2}\cos^2\theta, \\
m^2 + 1 &= \frac{u_1^2}{u_2^2} + 1 = \frac{u_1^2 + u_2^2}{u_2^2} = \frac{r^2}{u_2^2},\\
(m^2+1)r^2 - h^2 &= \frac{r^4}{u_2^2} - \frac{r^4}{u_2^2}\cos^2\theta
   = \frac{r^4}{u_2^2} \sin^2\theta, \\
\sqrt{(m^2+1)r^2 - h^2} &= \frac{r^2}{u_2} \sin\theta, \\
hm &= \frac{u_1}{u_2^2}(u_1^2 +u_2^2)\cos\theta = \frac{u_1r^2}{u_2^2}\cos\theta.
\end{align}

Therefore
\begin{align}
x &= \frac{\dfrac{u_1r^2}{u_2^2}\cos\theta \pm \dfrac{r^2}{u_2} \sin\theta}
         {\dfrac{r^2}{u_2^2}} \\
&= u_1 \cos\theta \pm u_2 \sin\theta, \\[1ex]
y &= \frac{u_1^2 +u_2^2}{u_2}\cos\theta 
    - \frac{u_1}{u_2}(u_1 \cos\theta \pm u_2 \sin\theta) \\
&= \frac1{u_2}((u_1^2 +u_2^2)\cos\theta  - (u_1^2 \cos\theta \pm u_1u_2 \sin\theta)) \\
&= \frac1{u_2}(u_2^2\cos\theta  \mp u_1u_2 \sin\theta) \\
&= u_2\cos\theta \mp u_1 \sin\theta, \\
\end{align}
which is the same as you get from the rotation matrix.
The $\pm$ and $\mp$ occur because your equations are not sufficient to distinguish a rotation by $\theta$ from a rotation by $-\theta,$ so we get solutions for two rotation matrices.

Comment: Thank you. That's quite a lot of work.

Comment: Yes, it might be easier to start with one of the matrix equations and verify that they satisfy your conditions. But most of the work here is just formatting and keeping track of which symbol means what. And it does give you uniqueness (up to reflection).

Answer (score 1):

Using complex numbers :
$$\begin{array}{lcl}
x + i y & = & (u_1 + i u_2) e^{i\theta} \\[3mm]
& = & (u_1 + i u_2)(\cos \theta + i \sin \theta) \\[3mm]
& = & u_1 \cos \theta - u_2 \sin \theta + i (u_1 \sin \theta + u_2 \cos \theta)
\end{array}$$
Hence :
$$\left\{\begin{array}{lcl}
x & = & u_1 \cos \theta - u_2 \sin \theta \\[3mm]
y & = & u_1 \sin \theta + u_2 \cos \theta
\end{array}\right.$$